# How to override static, factory-like method in subclasses

Tags: c#, generics, static, factory, creation

PROBLEM:

Static methods from a base class cannot be overriden, so I cannot compile this code (if I could, my design would be solved):

```
public abstract class ParametersBase
{
    public static abstract ParametersBase CreateDefault();  // THIS DOES NOT COMPILE!
}

public abstract class ParametersXml<T> where T : ParametersBase
{
    public static T LoadOrDefault(string fname)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture =
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

        T result;

        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        FileStream fs;

        try
        {
            using (fs = new FileStream(fname, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                result = (T)serializer.Deserialize(fs);
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException)
        {
            result = (T)typeof(T).GetMethod("CreateDefault").Invoke(null, new object[] { });
            using (fs = new FileStream(fname, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Read))
                serializer.Serialize(fs, result);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

CONTEXT:

I am trying to use generics to implement simple XML persistence in a set of subclasses representing groups of parameters along these lines:

- Each `Parameter` subclass has some set of properties that vary among subclasses;
- Each class will have a static `LoadOrDefault` method, and an instance `Save` method;
- Details of persistence (xml serialization and deserialization) will be encapsulated in a single class;
- Instantiation with default values will be put in each respective class.

I'm not even sure these should be the correct collaborations, I mean, every `ParameterBase` needs to be "wrapped" by a `ParametersXml<>`, while perhaps the right thing would be to encapsulate persistence code *inside* the base class, via inheritance...

Is this a good approach? Am I missing something?

Comment: What is wrong with `where T : ParametersBase, new()`?

Comment: You cannot mark `static` mehtods as `abstract` - as you have correctly stated, it gives a compile error. I am not sure what you're even hoping to achieve by doing this. What would you expect `ParametersBase.CreateDefault()` would do?

Comment: @kastermester I would expect to have, say, a subclass called `ThisParameters` and other `ThatParameters`, and calling `CreateDefault` on each one would return the appropriate instance with default property values already set.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I don' know what is wrong, actually I don't know about it. Why should I use it for?

Comment: @heltonbiker - the idea behind constraining T to have a default constructor is it let's you say `new T()` inside the generic method. And after that you could call `CreateDefault()` on the new instance of `T`. This lets you avoid having to mark the method as `static`.

Comment: @kastermester that sounds very reasonable. I'm gonna test it right now, but if you feel like posting this as an answer, I could gladly accept it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to elaborate what went on in the comments.

Marking a `static` method as `abstract` gives a compile time error. Mainly due to the fact that you cannot apply polymorphism in the general sense to abstract methods (there would never be a virtual method call).

What is needed in this instance is to not mark the method as `static`. Now the problem that arises from this is that one cannot be sure that one can acquire an instance of `T`. However, this can be changed by further constraining `T` to have a constructor taking no arguments, by changing the class definition to:

```
public abstract class ParametersXml<T> where T : ParametersBase, new()
```

Now in the `catch` in  `LoadOrDefault` it is possible to say:

```
result = new T().CreateDefault();
```

Notice how this is also a lot cleaner, and avoids both use of reflection and dirty type casts.

EDIT:
**Going even further**

As pointed out by @AlexeiLevenkov - assuming that `CreateDefault` is supposed to return an instance of its own type, and that the parameterless constructor is setting up `T` in its default state. One could even completely remove the need for `CreateDefault` and simply use the parameterless constructor as `CreateDefault`, thus changing the line in the catch handler to:

```
result = new T();
```

Comment: You may not even need `.CreateDefault()` assuming parameterless constructor actually sets up object into default state...

Comment: I never even thought that far, but that is absolutely correct.

Comment: I changed the code accordingly and it builds fine. I am still considering some variations, but this is surely a correct answer to my question, thanks!